# how to get dialect specific sql for a hibernate entity?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

we can see the hibenate `generated sql` while save or update.
now my requirement is, i am having an object(entity) which is already persisted.
now i want insert script for the object as per the `dialect` without manual generation.

Is there any possiblity?

Comment: I don't know (actually I don't think) Hibernate supports this out of the box. However, couldn't you just use your favourite SQL tool and generate the insert script from there?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit tricky, but possible.

In hibernate the `EntityPersister` is responsible for generating the sql. But it abstracts from sql so there is no API method to get the sql.

Nevertheless the `AbstractEntityPersister` which implements `EntityPersister` generates the sql. But also here is one problem: the sql generation methods are `protected`.

But we can still access them. Either through reflection or if we simply create a class within the same package.

So I created a class called `EntityPersisterAccess` in the same package as the `AbstractEntityPersister`, but of course in my project. (Example based on hibernate 3.6.7.Final)

```
package org.hibernate.persister.entity;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.engine.SessionFactoryImplementor;

public class EntityPersisterAccess {

    private SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementor;

    public EntityPersisterAccess(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        if (!(sessionFactory instanceof SessionFactoryImplementor)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                     "EntityPersisterAccess only works with a "
                     + SessionFactoryImplementor.class);
        }
        this.sessionFactoryImplementor = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory;
    }

    public String getInsertSql(Class<?> entityClass) {
        return getInsertSql(entityClass.getCanonicalName())
    }

    public String getInsertSql(String entityName) {
        String insertSql = null;
        EntityPersister ep = sessionFactoryImplementor.getEntityPersister(entityName);
        if(entityPersister instanceof AbstractEntityPersister ){
            AbstractEntityPersister aep = (AbstractEntityPersister) entityPersister;
            boolean[] includeProperty = aep.getPropertyInsertability();
            insertSql = aep.generateInsertString(true, includeProperty);
        }
        return insertSql ;
    }
}
```

You can than simply do something like this in your code

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = ....;
EntityPersisterAccess epa = new EntityPersisterAccess(sessionFactory);
String insertSql = epa.getInsertSql(Person.class); // some entity class
System.out.println(insertSql);
```

In my tests the output is

```
insert into PERSON (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, BIRTHDAY, ADDRESS_ID_FK, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, null)
```

**benefit of this approach**: The `EntityPersisterAccess` completly encapsulates the hibernate internals from the client code that uses it. Thus you 'only' have to change this class when migrating to a new hibernate version - hopefully :)

**PS:** There might be more to consider and to implement in the `EntityPersisterAccess`, but this example should be a good starting point.